# Is it possible to find a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $B = \{f(x) : x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B=\{f(x):x\in\mathbb N\}$, where $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$.
Is it possible to find function $f$ such that $B$ is an interval?

Comment: $|B|=\aleph_0$ yet $|(a,b)|=\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: $\sqrt{x-1}$?..

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. An interval of the form $(a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $[a,b)$, or $(a,b]$  for $a<b$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ contains uncountably many elements of the real line. $B=\{f(n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable set.

Answer (score 4):

this is probably cheating, but in some definitions there is defined a 'degenerate' interval $[a,a]\equiv\{a\}$ so it follows you could use $f(n)=a$ hence $\{f(n):n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{a\}=[a,a]$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $B$ is the range of $f$. So $f$ defines a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $B$ (as $B$ is the range of $f$). Therefore the cardinality of $B$ is at most the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$. This rules out the possibilities $[a, b]$ with $a < b$, as they are uncountable. Likewise for $(a, b)$, $(a, b]$, $[a, b)$, and infinite intervals. The only possible intervals that are left are the empty set and singletons.

Note that $B = \emptyset$ is impossible as the range of a function on a non-empty set is non-empty.

The only possibility that remains is that $B$ is a singleton; that is, $B = \{a\} = [a, a]$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This can be achieved with the constant function $f(x) = a$.

Comment: ah, you beat me! that was my same idea :-p

Comment: @oldrinb: I don't know why you think $[a, a]$ may be cheating. An interval $I$ is a subset of the real numbers such that for any two numbers in $I$, every number between them is also in $I$. The set $[a, a] = \{a\}$ satisfies this property.